# DB2: fill a dummy field with values in for loop while a select

Tags: sql, db2

I want to fill a dummy field with values in a for loop during a select:

Somethinhg like (table account e.g. has a field "login")

select login,(for i= 1 to 3 {list=list.login.i.","}) as list from account

The result should be

```
login |  list
aaa  |   aaa1,aaa2,aaa3
bbb  |   bbb1,bbb2,bbb3
ccc  |   ccc1,ccc2,ccc3
```

Can someone please help me if that is possible !!!!

Many Thanks !

Comment: Create a UDF (user-defined function), which you can call in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an one-off task and the size of your loop is fixed, you can make up a table of integers and do a cartesian product with your table containing the column `login`:

```
SELECT ACC.LOGIN || NUMBRS.NUM FROM
ACCOUNT ACC, TABLE (
 SELECT '1' AS NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
 SELECT '2' AS NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
 SELECT '3' AS NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) NUMBRS
```

which will give you strings like 'aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3' one string per row. Then, you can aggregate these strings with [LISTAGG](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html).

If the size is not fixed, you can always make up a temporary table and fill it up with appropriate data and use it instead of the `NUMBRS` table above.